# How to put Ints together

Tags: java, int

I need help with a hw that i have for java. Im in highschool so we haven't learned too much into the harder stuff. I need the user to input two numbers a starting and an ending. I then need to combine those two numbers and find how many odd and evens are in it. I wanna know how i can combine the numbers to then use them as a int so i can do more with them.

```
out.println("Please enetr a starting number");
int num1 = input.nextInt();
out.println("Please enter and ending number");
int num2 = input.nextInt();
```

By combining the numbers I mean if you have 3 and 4 it would output 34.

Comment: Using the plus sign (as would be stated on the second or third step of any decent Java tutorial)

Comment: combine those two numbers? Please give us some examples.

Comment: "Combine" how? Add? Multiply? Shift one by the other? Make a complex number `num1 + i * num2`?

Comment: Do you mean 3 and 4 becomes 34?

Comment: @MathewsMathai yes

Comment: So if the user enters a 12 and a 3, does that become 15 or 123?

Comment: @pczeus It would be the second one - 123

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't combine 2 int's by concatenating them easily.
Since you are receiving user input from the command line anyway, it is easier to handle the initial input as Strings, concatenate the Strings and then convert to an integer like this:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter the first number:");
String first = sc.next();
System.out.println("Enter the second number:");
String second = sc.next();
int combinedNumber = Integer.parseInt(first + second);
System.out.println("You entered the number: " + combinedNumber);
```

Answer (score 0):

`int num3 = Integer.parseInt("" + num1 + num2);`

Breakdown:

`int num3` - declare new `int` variable

`Integer.parseInt()` - process a `String` variable to find out the integer value it contains

`"" + num1 + num2` - convert `num1` to a `String`, then concatenate `num2`

Here is the documentation for [`Integer.parseInt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt-java.lang.String-)

Answer (score 0):

Let's combine.

```
out.println("Please enetr a starting number"); 
int num1 = input.nextInt(); 
out.println("Please enter and ending number"); 
int num2 = input.nextInt();
String n1=Integer.toString(num1);
String n2=Integer.toString(num2);
String combine=n1.concat(n2);
int combNum=Integer.parseInt(combine);
```

What did I do?

- Converted both the integers to string.
- Then concatenated them that is joined the strings together.
- Then I converted the final string to an integer.

This is a very basic convertion. You could also skip some of the statements and do it more efficiently. This is just to give you an idea. Explore it.